# Keyerror while using defaultdict

Tags: python, json, defaultdict

I am trying to use defaultdict(dict) to parse data from json that has nested keys of 'date' and 'value'.

The date key is always presented with the corresponding value but if there is no data on the 'value' -key at all, it is completely omitted.

This is causing me a problem with defaultdict because when on the first row the 'value' key is missing but is present on the second row it raises an KeyError: 'value'.

Any ideas how i could work around this and have the value in there even thought its missing on the first row.

DATA:

```
{
"metric": "complexity",
   "history": [
       {
        "date": "2019-09-10T15:24:33+0200",
        "value": "54"
       },
       {
        "date": "2019-12-24T11:26:42+0100"
       }
```

CODE:

```
dates_to_values = defaultdict(dict)
    for metric in metrics['measures']:
        metric_value = metric['metric']
        for hist in metric['history']:
            dates_to_values[hist['date']][metric_value] = hist['value']
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code example?

Comment: @CoryNezin edited example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in `defaultdict` but in `hist`. If `hist` is always be a dict then use `hist.get('value')` when key is not always present in it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very simple fix and clear answer!